# Tooltips ubicación dinámica

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una gráfica y cada barra tiene un tooltip asociado, no todos los tooltips se muestran donde deberían (en la parte superior de la barra asociada). Ejemplo:

El siguiente tooltip deberia estar sobre la barra del 12 oct

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cada tooltip debe tener su posición según la barra

El código es este: https://codepen.io/linacsm/pen/vYBrMJO

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Tan solo tienes que cambiar el ancho en posición de pantalla en el fichero JavaScript a un valor mayor.

```
if (Math.round(anchoEnPosicion > 3000)) { //=> de 884 a 3000 por ejemplo
    jQuery(tooltip[0]).removeClass("left");
    jQuery(tooltip[0]).addClass("right");
    var d = coordenadaXElemento + anchoElemento / 2 + 10;
    x = Math.round(d) * 0.50;
    y = coordenadaYElemento + altoElemento / 2 - 165;
} else {
    jQuery(tooltip[0]).removeClass("right");
    jQuery(tooltip[0]).addClass("left");
    x = coordenadaXElemento + anchoElemento / 2 - 10;
    y = coordenadaYElemento + altoElemento / 2 - 165;
}
```